# BQ Get labels from information schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to get the labels of all the BQ tables in a project.
Currently the only way I found is to loop over all the tables and retrieve the labels.

```
        tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)
        for table in tables:
            if table.labels:
                for label, value in table.labels.items():
```

This approach works but is time consuming.
Is there any possibility to get the labels using a unique BQ query?
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` doesn't return the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an option to return the labels from the `INFORMATION SCHEMA`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA_OPTIONS
WHERE
  schema_name = 'schema'
  AND option_name = 'labels';
```